# Angular2 tsd missing from github

Tags: typescript, angular, tsd

Last two days I've tried to install the typescript definition file for angular2 and it results in an empty result in the terminal. Then the link for the github project is also missing -
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular2/angular2.d.ts

Anyone know about this or have a new link?

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 now ships with TypeScript definitions out of the box. You don't need an external package manager to bring in defs for angular 2.

Comment: How do you initialize it then? My tsd file doesnt know how to pick it up....so I don't have any intelli-sense right now.Thanks dude!

Comment: `so I don't have any intelli-sense right now.Thanks dude`: It should pickup from `node_modules/angular2` with `moduleResolution:node`.

Comment: Ah perfect thanks so much for all the help tonight!!